# How to fill WPF DataGridView from related tables using LINQ query?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I am trying to fill my WPF dataGridView from two related tables using LINQ to Entity model.
Trying to Display these two tables

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

But the BatchName column is not displaying any data. I am using following LINQ query:

```
public List<StudentViewModel> SelectNamesAndBatches()
        {
    var students = (from s in db.Students
                            join b in db.Batches
                            on s.BatchId equals b.Id
                            select new StudentViewModel
                            {
                                Name = s.Name,
                                Gender = s.Gender,
                                Age = s.Age,
                                BatchId = b.Id,
                                BatchName = b.BatchName
                            }).ToList();

            return students;
}
```

My DatagridView XML code:

```
<DataGrid Name="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="500" Height="200" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Name}">

                </DataGridTextColumn>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Width="50" Binding="{Binding Age}">

                </DataGridTextColumn>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gender" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Gender}">

                </DataGridTextColumn>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Batches Name" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Batches.BatchName}">

                </DataGridTextColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

This is how I am filling datagridview:

```
dg.ItemsSource = new StudentFactory().SelectNamesAndBatches();
```

Please guide me about what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NiazBro, try this:

```
var students = (from s in db.Students.Include("Batches")
                            select new StudentViewModel
                            {
                                Name = s.Name,
                                Gender = s.Gender,
                                Age = s.Age,
                                BatchId = s.Batches.Id,
                                BatchName = s.Batches.BatchName
                            }).ToList();

            return students;
```

This assumes that your Students model expresses this one to many link with Batches.

Comment: Thanks @Ibrahim, after a couple of changes it worked. Can you send me a link of a tutorial related to this? I just can't get my head clear on this stuff.